# SCSS and Express JS

Tags: express, npm, module, sass

How can I set up Express to use style.scss file instead of style.sass ?

It only recognizes style.sass with the following configuration.

app.js

```
// Sass setup
app.use(require('node-sass-middleware')({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public/sass'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'),
  indentedSyntax: true,
  sourceMap: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));
```

Structure tree

```
-public 

--stylesheets 

---style.css
---style.css.map
---style.sass
```

I would like to use style.scss instead of style.sass.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `scss` files, you can remove the key/value `intentedSyntax`. This option allows you to use scss files

```
app.use(require('node-sass-middleware')({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public/sass'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'),
  sourceMap: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));
```

However, say if you used `indentedSyntax` but wanted to use the file extension `scss` - then you'll have to make a decision.

1. use indentedSyntax (and keep `.sass`)
2. use `.scss` and ensure you have brackets in your scss files.

If you're using sass 3.x then you can use the above proposed solution.